# How to uninstall and reinstall GNOME 3.10?

Tags: 13.04, gnome

I installed GNOME 3.10. I had GNOME 3.8 and liked it very much. Unfortunately, with 3.10 it seems like something went wrong. None of the backgrounds work and the buttons to log out and shut down are missing.

How can I uninstall and reinstall GNOME 3.10? I am running Ubuntu 13.04.

I originally installed it by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Comment: How did you install gnome 3.10?

Comment: You are looking for this http://askubuntu.com/a/175564/169736

Comment: Is more likely that you still have problems with Gnome 3.10. If it doesn't work you either report a bug or remove the unstable version.

Comment: I think i mess it up because i was using gnome 3.8 while it was installing it ...dumb of me. :( now my software center is not working and i get many errors when i log on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
```

Then reconfigure either GDM or LightDM, whichever one you like

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

OR

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

If you don't get 3.8 back, do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install a specific version of a package via equality sign:

```
apt-get install <package name>=<version>
```

But first you have to find out which versions are available by:

```
apt-cache madison <package name>
```

For example with the package binutils:

```
# apt-cache madison binutils
  binutils | 2.22-6ubuntu1.1 | http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
  binutils | 2.22-6ubuntu1.1 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
  binutils | 2.22-6ubuntu1 | http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
  binutils | 2.22-6ubuntu1 | http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main Sources
  binutils | 2.22-6ubuntu1.1 | http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main Sources
  binutils | 2.22-6ubuntu1.1 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main Sources
```

Then take one of the version numbers the command with the `apt-get install` command, for example:

```
apt-get install binutils=2.22-6ubuntu1.1
```

Comment: Dont i have to uninstall old version first? how can i do this?

Comment: in your case its apt-get remove gnome-shell