# How to install last version of unity in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, unity

Can you tell me how install last unity version in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: See this answer:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/356726/how-to-uninstall-and-reinstall-gnome-3-10/356739#356739

Comment: Any reason why you want to do this?

Comment: @chaos that question is about Gnome 3 not Unity

Comment: @Braiam yes, but he can use same solution: installing a specific version of a package.

Comment: @chaos there is not newer version of unity for precise in any repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there isn't the 7.10 package of Unity available in repositories, nor PPA's. Hence you should build from sources and backport the build dependencies, but still that doesn't assure you that your system will stay stable.