# Downgrade gnome 3.10 to gnome 3.8?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, downgrade

I found some problems with gnome 3.10, so I want to downgrade to the 3.8.

My ubuntu versio is 13.10.

Comment: Did you add a PPA to update default gnome 3.8 in raring to 3.10? If so, wich PPA did you add?

Comment: I found this question, that's help me http://askubuntu.com/questions/356726/how-to-uninstall-and-reinstall-gnome-3-10?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Is it an Ubuntu version that came with Unity and you then installed Gnome or it is the Gnome Ubuntu version?

I wouldn't recommend to downgrade but yes to do the following:

sudo apt-get -f update

sudo apt get -f upgrade

sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade

It will fix any problems you have, if you want Gnome and you installed it over Unity you may also want to clean install:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/GetUbuntuGNOME

It is not a direct solution for your question but I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

^ as above, i upgraded gnome to 3.10 from 3.8. i'm using ubuntu 13.10 (zorin distro).

the above suggestion:

> sudo apt-get -f update
>
> sudo apt get -f upgrade
>
> sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade

doesn't seem to work. i have also tried:

> sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
>
> sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
>
> sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
>
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

to no avail. any other suggestions?

as for the problem: after upgrading to 3.10 it all became a mess. desktop background greyed out, all icons disappeared. i don't recall what i typed in the terminal, i think "startx" and since then, i've been unable to log in. i get the same screen as i would if i had logged out, but my password no longer works. as guest log-in is disabled, i effectively have way to access the desktop.

i have a feeling that if i can access the desktop again i can tweak the desktop to the way it was before. reinstall is last resort -- any recommendations?